# Pause Javascript slider for few seconds on clicking a button below it

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I have downloaded [Menucool](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider) slider code. I am using the demo code present in the above link. My requirement is , when I click on the radio button below the slider, I need the slider to pause for few seconds ( for me it's 10 seconds).The default interval is 2.6 seconds.

I have tried to change the time interval by using Jquery onclick.But it is not working.

Below is my html code.

```
<div id="sliderFrame">
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="images/image-slider-1.jpg" />
        <img src="images/image-slider-2.jpg" />
        <img src="images/image-slider-3.jpg" />
        <img src="images/image-slider-4.jpg" />
        <img src="images/image-slider-5.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript code for slider options is

```
var sliderOptions=
{
    sliderId: "slider",
    startSlide: 0,
    effect: "series1",
    effectRandom: false,
    pauseTime: 2600,
    transitionTime: 500,
    slices: 12,
    boxes: 8,
    hoverPause: 1,
    autoAdvance: true,
    captionOpacity: 0.3,
    captionEffect: "fade",
    thumbnailsWrapperId: "thumbs",
    m: false,
    license: "mylicense"
};
var imageSlider=new mcImgSlider(sliderOptions);
```

I have tried to change the pausetime to 10000 in another function which executes after clicking the radio buttons.The code is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){

    $(".active").click(function(){
        alert("hi");
        var sliderOptions=
        {
            sliderId: "slider",
            startSlide: 0,
            effect: "series1",
            effectRandom: false,
            pauseTime: 10000,
            transitionTime: 500,
            slices: 12,
            boxes: 8,
            hoverPause: 1,
            autoAdvance: true,
            captionOpacity: 0.3,
            captionEffect: "fade",
            thumbnailsWrapperId: "thumbs",
            m: false,
            license: "mylicense" 
        };      
    })
    var imageSlider=new mcImgSlider(sliderOptions);
})
</script>
```

Can someone please help me how to achieve this functionality..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Methods](http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo4#builtinfunctions) supported by Menucool slider library.

**pauseTime** option will be used only on mouseout, mouseover events.

To fulfill your requirements, you have to use "switchAuto" function.

Here is the [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d574qa1u/7/).

Javascript :

```
$("#changeInterval").change(function(){
    var that = this;
    if(this.checked && imageSlider.getAuto()) {
        imageSlider.switchAuto(); // pause the animation (auto: false)
        setTimeout(function(){
            that.checked = false; // uncheck the radio button
            imageSlider.switchAuto(); // resume the animation (auto: true)
        }, 10000); // 10 seconds
    }

});
```

In the above code, I am binding "change" event on radio button (id: changeInterval).

By default in the option list, **auto** value has been set to true so when we call "**switchAuto**" function, it changes the **auto** value to false which stops animation. And after 10 seconds I am again calling the "switchAuto" function to resume the animation.

In this way you can pause animation for specified time.